# Two UPDATE queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have tried two queries in order to update a column

Update query #1:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT=0 --This causes the @@rowcount to be > 0

while @@rowcount>0
begin
   set rowcount 10000

   update r
   set Comp = t.Comp
   from [dbo].[Vente] r 
   inner join [dbo].tempBudgeT t with (index (index_Budget )) 
                 on t.[Code Site] = r.[Code Site]
                 and t.[Code Structure] = r.[Code Structure]
                 and t.[Date Time] = convert(date, r.[Date Time])
   where r.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000'
     and r.Comp is null
end

SET rowcount 0
```

Update query #2:

```
 DECLARE @Counter INT=0 --This causes the @@rowcount to be > 0

 while @@rowcount > 0
 begin
     set rowcount 10000

     update [dbo].[Vente] 
     set Comp = (select top 1 t.comp
                 from [dbo].[Budget] t with (index (index_Budget))
                 where t.[Code Site] = [dbo].[Vente].[Code Site]
                   and t.[Code Rayon] = substring([dbo].[Vente].[Code Structure], 1, 4)
                   and t.[Date Time] = convert(date, [dbo].[Vente].[Date Time])
                   and [dbo].[Vente].[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000'
                   and [dbo].[Vente].Comp is null)
 end

 SET rowcount 0
```

My problem is the second query is faster than the first query but it didn't work, comp is not updated with the second query ? Where is the problem ?

Comment: Troubleshoot by changing the update to a select and see what gets returned.  If it's nothing, start removing filters, one by one, until something is returned.  Once you identify the field, select it and compare the actual result to what you expected.

Comment: Because second query is wrong and @Backs query seem to be ok but I don't think it is better than your first query.Now in your first query  I don't understand why you are using while loop and rowCount .when it will loop only once.What is your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `[dbo].[Vente]` and `[dbo].[Budget]` have not join, and update condition in subquery:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0 --This causes the @@rowcount to be > 0

WHILE @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 10000

    UPDATE v
    SET Comp = (
            SELECT TOP 1 t.comp
            FROM [dbo].[Vente] v
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Budget] t WITH (INDEX (index_Budget)) t.[Code Site] = v.[Code Site]
            WHERE t.[Code Site] = v.[Code Site]
                AND t.[Code Rayon] = substring([dbo].[Vente].[Code Structure], 1, 4)
                AND t.[Date Time] = convert(DATE, [dbo].[Vente].[Date Time])
                AND [dbo].[Vente].[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000'
                AND [dbo].[Vente].Comp IS NULL
            )
END

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```